# Calling one-parameter function with two arguments?

Tags: f#

I have this code:

```
type Sym = (string * float) list

let rec lookup v = function
  | (v', k) :: vtab -> if v = v' then k else lookup v vtab
  | (_ : Sym)    -> failwith ("unbound: " + v)
```

To me, it looks like that `lookup` takes one argument `v`. But then we do `lookup v vtab` - now it seems like two arguments are being passed to `lookup`? How can this be valid when `lookup` only takes one argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does take two parameters. The first one is `v`, the second one comes from `function`.

In F# `function` is syntactic sugar for `match`. More specifically, the word `function` means `fun x -> match x with`.

So you can read your code as:

```
let rec lookup v = fun x -> match x with
  | (v', k) :: vtab -> if v = v' then k else lookup v vtab
  | (_ : Sym)    -> failwith ("unbound: " + v)
```

Which in turn is the same as:

```
let rec lookup v x = match x with
  | (v', k) :: vtab -> if v = v' then k else lookup v vtab
  | (_ : Sym)    -> failwith ("unbound: " + v)
```